# Class doesn't exist error while defining another method inside a DWR class

Tags: java, dwr

I'm using DWR for Ajax calls in my code and I've this class defined which works fine when I'm calling the method `locationList` like `ManageLocation.locationList(selectedVal,displayInfo);`

However, if I try to do the same thing with another method from the javascript code  like this `ManageLocation.test(selectedVal,displayInfo);`, it's not even hitting this class and I get a Javascript error that this method test doesn't exist.

```
public class ManageLocation {


WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
ServletContext cs = ctx.getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext webctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(cs);


CompanyLocationManager clMgr = (CompanyLocationManager) webctx.getBean("companyLocationManager");

public String locationList(String val) {

    return clMgr.getCompanyLocationByQuery("name LIKE '" + val + "%'").toString();


}

public String test(Integer val) {
    return clMgr.getCompanyLocationByQuery("where id='" + val + "'").toString();




}
```

}

Is there anything like I can have only one method inside the DWR related classes?